# To have [noun] of [noun]: adjectival construction or meaninful phrase with specific connotations?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrases, auxiliary-verbs

In the song [*Faith of the Heart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faith_of_the_Heart), as in its title, you have two nouns connected with the preposition [*of*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of?s=t). Please consider the following segment for instance:

> Cause I've got *faith of the heart*.
>  I'm going where my heart
>   will take me.
>  I've got faith to believe.
>  I can do
>   anything.
>  I've got *strength of the soul*.
>  And no one's
>   going to bend or break me.
>
> [ *Faith of the Heart*, by Diane Warren, for movie and television (sample) ]

It's formatted in a way that feels indicative of the material of substance (of the second term), but I think it's rather the *origin*, like with the preposition [*from*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/from?s=t). At the same time it doesn't use a personal pronoun i.e. it's not *faith in my heart*; neither is it *I have a faithful heart*. What I'm trying to describe seems to be further emphasized by the fact you have the verb *to [have](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have?s=t)* (*I've got*) i.e. it's not *to be* as in *I'm strong of/with the soul*, it's not phrased as an attribute but rather as something you *possess/hold*.

---

1. Why is it *of* and not *from* the heart/soul; is it really about the
   *origin*; is the type of origin better suited for either preposition in this very case or is it just a choice?
2. What does using *to have* do here that *to be*    doesn't/couldn't
   do; is that *to undergo*; does the native speaker pick up the bill
   of materials feeling or any other connotation with this sort of
   phrasing?
3. Can you provide an idiomatic and/or well known example of this
   sort of [ to have + noun + of + noun ] construction (without a
   personal pronoun) which would better showcase its meaning and
   whether there's more to this than the sum of its parts (1+2)?

Comment: It's a song lyric. Writers use all kinds of devices to force the lyrics into a metrical scheme. The verb _to have_ in _I've got_ was used for that reason. There's no grammatical significance there. Same with _faith of the heart_ as opposed to _my heart is faithful_ or similar. It's just a poetic equivalance with _strength of the soul._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you, your comment is somewhat reassuring. I completely understand the use of such devices as those you speak of in context. Nevertheless, as often, this is just an opportunity to explore the language. If you want, you may state in an answer that there is no distinct grammatical significance to such a construction. I thought I had picked up on something which I wasn't familiar with. Thank you!

Comment: It may well be that someone else will detect some deep grammatical significance in the lyric and provide an answer more insightful than my desultory comment. Don't give up yet.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks, I hear you. I'm much less worried about grammar as the question seems to imply. I guess in some way I'm incidentally asking indeed is that _my heart is faithful_ or something along the lines of _I'm feeling faith flowing through my heart_, which is somewhat different I would think. Is saying _I have faith of the heart_ for _my heart is faithful_ less idiomatic, old or imprecise? Anyways, we'll see. Thanks!